# Obtener el usuario logueado en laravel usando el guard "api"

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-7

Tengo una ruta PUT en *Laravel 7*, necesito obtener los datos del usuario logueado en el método del controlador que recibe esa petición (`update()`).

Si pongo la ruta en las *rutas web*, el usuario se obtiene:

```
$usuario = Auth::user();
```

Si situó la ruta en las *rutas api*, en el método compruebo que se ha autenticado un usuario:

```
logger('@' . (Auth::guard('api')->check()) ? 1 : 0);
```

*El log imprime un 1.*

Pero no se como obtener el usuario. He probado:

```
$usuario = $request->user(); 
$usuario = $request->user('api');
$usuario = Auth::guard('api')->user();
// $request se recibe como parámetro del método
```

En todos los casos `$usuario` es `null`.

Comment: ¿Estás importando Auth en tu controlador? `use Auth`

Comment: @Jacobo si claro, lo necesito para poder hacer por ejemplo: `Auth::guard('api')->check()`

Comment: Y si tratas con el helper de está forma `auth('api')->user();`

Comment: @BetaM `auth('api')->user();` functiona. Muchas gracias.