# Funcionamiento helper auth() de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar `auth()` y `auth('api')` en Laravel?

Entiendo que con `auth('api')` se pregunta si se ha logueado un usuario con el *guard* "api"... ¿correcto?

¿Usar`auth()` es general (independiente de si estamos en web o api)? ¿o usa el *guard* establecido por defecto en "config/auth.php", para el caso "web"?

Pregunta relacionada:
[Obtener el usuario logueado en laravel usando el guard "api"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417807/obtener-el-usuario-logueado-en-laravel-usando-el-guard-api)

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-auth

Comment: Tienes razon para el metodo auth podria desirce que se puede usar en web y el prefijo API para dispositivos moviles o alguna aplicacion que hagas por ejemplo en angular o react y necesites consumir apis desde laravel, poder obtener un usuario o iniciar sesion, el prefijo api puede englobar todo eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas el archivo *auth* dentro de **`config/auth.php`**, donde se documenta el *array de defaults* que dice y cito:

> This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password reset options for your application

Que se puede traducir como:

> Esta opción controla el *guardia de autenticación* y las *opciones de reseteo de contraseñas* por default para tu aplicación.

Luego entonces podemos revisar lo siguiente:

**Caso 1**

Podemos examinar cual es el *guard* usado *por default* de la siguiente manera:

```
dd(App(AuthFactory::class)->guard());
```

Que nos daría una salida como esta:

```
Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard {#377 ▼
  #name: "web"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
  ...............
  ...............
```

Entonces como puedes observar es `web` aquel que se utiliza si no se pasa como argumento alguno en específico.

**Caso 2**

Por ejemplo si tenemos un *guard* con el nombre de `algoSimple`, lo podemos usar de la siguiente manera:

```
dd(App(AuthFactory::class)->guard('algoSimple'));
```

Con esta salida:

```
Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard {#377 ▼
  #name: "algoSimple"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
  ...................
  ...................
```

Como extra, si tratamos de trabajar con un *guard* inexistente o mal escrito obtendremos algo como esto:

> InvalidArgumentException
> Auth guard [algosimple] is not defined.

En todos los casos nos estamos apoyando del *facade `App`* para interactuar con el *service container* y obtener las salidas que te estoy mostrando.

**Comentarios finales**:

- Considera revisar el código fuente en el archivo de *helpers* sobre la función `auth`, esto te dará mucho panorama de su funcionamiento
- Siempre y cuando no elimines el array de *defaults* podrás usar el método `guard` sin argumentos, en caso contrario te daría un error que dice: **Auth guard [] is not defined.**
- El método `guard` esta definido que puede recibir o no un parámetro, en caso de si recibirlo es un *string* y este sería el nombre del que pretendas usar

**Referencias**

- [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#simple-bindings)
- Interface **`Factory`**: **`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory.php`**
- helpers.php: **`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`**

Comment: Si entendi bien la explicacion: ¿Solo se refiere a un nombre (web-api-algosimple)?

Comment: El nombre que pasas deberá existir declarado como *guard* en caso contrario indicaría el error de que no está definido, el que coloque solo es un ejemplo